# How can I create a musical sheet using sprites?(Ocarina of time )

Tags: unity, c#, sprites, ui-design

I am looking to make a musical sheet similar to the image below:

[image: Ocarina of time image reference]

I want to:

- use sprites prefabs
- have each sprite correspond to a different line
- Move down notes are more are being played
- have tail end notes disappear or go outside of text view (like when you type past a search bar)

I am unsure if there is a UI asset in Unity that can perform what I just mentioned. I was thinking could just instantiate the prefabs in the right positions, shift them down, then delete the tail end prefabs as more are being played. Outside of that, I'm lost.

Comment: The behaviour you describe sounds more like Guitar Hero than Ocarina of Time. How have you tried spawning and moving your prefabs so far, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I haven't yet. But I know how to do that. I was just trying to see if there was a Unity UI component that could do what I am trying to achieve. And guitar hero is a perfect example of what I am trying to achieve. I can use that for reference. @DMGregory.

Comment: To clarify I meant trying to see if there was Unity functionality that can spawn sprites on different lines. I guessing there isn't and I just have to use a game object and positioning to get that effect.

Comment: Sounds to me like you should follow through with your guess, and ask for help here if you run into a snag you can't solve with what you know so far.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your time anyway.

Comment: I managed to do a similar thing with textmeshpro and richtext to display sheet music. But it was a bit of a hassle (had to do manual measurements on the font I used to get the positions right). Probably easier to just use a texture and modify its transform or its shader.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to forego the UI approach and instead used a game object with four empty children used positions. I use 1 sprite to make up the display and have others spawn on the display. Then I just set two colliders at the end of each end of the display to push back notes and despawn others.

Comment: This answer would be even better with a code sample, or diagrams/screenshots demonstrating your setup.